# How can i access real time driver log (not with a lag of 5 min) other than Azure databricks sparkUI

Tags: monitoring, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to integrate the driver logs to Control-M scheduler.

How can i access real time driver log (not with a lag of 5 min) other than Azure databricks sparkUI. Using some API or accessing the location of real time written logs.

Also I am planning to do elastic analysis on top of it.

Comment: Did you already try accessing the driver cluster via terminal, and read the log from there?

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman  The logs are delivered at a lag of 5 min. I want real time driver logs. See the link:  https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/configure.html?_ga=2.180512545.742397901.1618071966-985245219.1618071966#cluster-log-delivery

Answer (score 3):

Such things (real-time collection of metrics or logs) are usually done via installation of some agent (for example, filebeat) via [init scripts](https://docs.databricks.com/clusters/init-scripts.html) (global or cluster-level init scripts).

The actual script content heavily depends on the type of the agent used, but Databricks' documentation contains some examples of that:

- [Blog post](https://databricks.com/blog/2017/06/01/apache-spark-cluster-monitoring-with-databricks-and-datadog.html) on setting Datadog integration
- [Notebook](https://docs.databricks.com/_static/notebooks/datadog-init-script.html) that shows how setup init script for Datadog

Comment: Is there a free alternative to this? Is there a way for me to deliver the logs to say a database of my choice?

Comment: yes, you can send logs to whatever you need - just write corresponding init script that will start, for example, filebeat

Comment: Sounds really great! Do you have some kind of reference for how this can be done? Apologies for the trouble, I have not used filebeat before.

Comment: I have created a question here Alex and I would really appreciate an answer, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73120319/databricks-init-script-to-send-logs-to-delta-table-using-filebeat